# Eclipse Java Formatter - Newline before closing parentheses

Tags: java, eclipse, formatting

Is it possible to configure the Eclipse Java Formatter to insert a newline before the closing parenthesis of expressions, method declarations, and method calls?

Notice the desired behavior on the lines marked with "XX" below.

=method declaration=

```
private static void fun1(
    int param1,
    String param2
){ // XX - notice this is on a new line

}
```

=method call=

```
fun1(
    1,
    "param2"
); // XX
```

=expression=

```
int a = (
    (
        (
            1 + 2
        )*23 // XX
    ) - 4 // XX
); // XX
```

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this?  Would you mind posting an answer if you did?

Comment: Currently I add an additional newline so that the auto-formatter does not collapse it. This litters my code with empty lines, but still looks better to me.

Comment: The feature request has now a change in review :D
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=370540

Answer (score 2):

The first Eclipse Integration Build allowing this is: Eclipse Neon 4.6 M7 Build id: I20160427-2000

To get closing parenthesis on new lines change the option

"Windows" -> "Preferences" -> "Java" -> "Code Style" -> "Formatter" -> "Edit..." -> "Parentheses" -> "Parentheses Positions" -> "Method declaration"

to

"Separate lines if not empty"

This will make the examples "method declaration" and "method call" work.

I'm not sure if the "expression" example can be made to work yet.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to figure this out as well and found that this may help:

Windows" -> "Preferences" -> "Java" -> "Code Style" -> "Formatter" -> "Edit..." -> "Parentheses"

Set "Method Declaration" (beginning of line) to "Separated lines if Wrapped"
Set "Method Invocation" (End of line) to "Separated lines if Wrapped"

Then got to "Line Wrapping" -> "Method Declarations"
Set "Parameters" to "Wrap where Necessary" and "Force Split, Even if line shorter than maximum line width."

Then got to "Line Wrapping" -> "Function Declarations"
Set "Arguments" to "Wrap where Necessary" and "Force Split, Even if line shorter than maximum line width."
Set "Object allocation arguments" to "Wrap where Necessary" and "Force Split, Even if line shorter than maximum line width."

Then got to "Line Wrapping" -> "Expressions"
Set "Binary Expressions" to "Wrap where Necessary", "Force Split, Even if line shorter than maximum line width.", and "Wrap Before Operator"

Hope this works for you. Take care.